# Google maps custom marker icon configuration from sprite sheet with retina support

Tags: google-maps-api-3

My Google map uses a custom Marker pin loaded from a sprite sheet, everything works as expected for 1x, 2x, and 3x displays expect @2x, and @3x the image shows up as twice of three times the size of the original image.

If I try and scale it back to to the 1x dimensions when displaying at @2x and @3x the marker shows up without the image.

Googleing around suggests that I am doing everything right, Icon configuration is based on the documentation.

Is anyone able to spot what might be wrong with my `scaledImage` configuration?

```
if(devicePixelRatio > 1) {
  pinImage['scaledSize'] = new google.maps.Size(15, 36);
}
```

Code extract from JavaScript:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

// Retina support
var requireImagePrefix = "";
var devicePixelRatio = (window.devicePixelRatio===undefined?1:window.devicePixelRatio);

if(devicePixelRatio == 2) {
  requireImagePrefix = "@2x";
}
else if(devicePixelRatio == 3) {
  requireImagePrefix = "@3x";
}

// Image for the marker
var pinImage = {
  url: "/assets/sprite" + requireImagePrefix + ".png",
  size: new google.maps.Size(15*devicePixelRatio, 36*devicePixelRatio),
  origin: new google.maps.Point(430*devicePixelRatio, 20*devicePixelRatio),
};

if(devicePixelRatio > 1) {
  pinImage['scaledSize'] = new google.maps.Size(15, 36);
}

var officeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: hqLocation,
  map: map,
  title: "Anomaly HQ",
  icon: pinImage,
  optimized: false
});
```

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

My error in the above are:

- The `scaledSize` parameter is meant to be the dimensions of the 1x sprite
- We don't need to multiply the `size` and `origin` parameters by the aspect ratio

I have posted the updated solution as a Git oh [Github](https://gist.github.com/devraj/ca0048d136a61bc0de95)